# Recoverable and Cascading Schedule

Tags: database, database-design, data-binding, database-schema

In database Transaction management. A strict Schedule is

```
    T1        T2     

    R(A)
    W(A)
              R(A)
              W(A)
   Commit;
              Commit;
```

This is a Strict Schedule. since we are following the basic rule. if T2 Reads a value written by T1 then T1 commit should be before T2 Commit.

This schedule is also subset of Cascading Schedule. since if T1 fails T2 will be rolled back. thus Strict Schedule is subset of Cascading Schedule. This Schedule is also recoverable schedule. **So can we conclude that a Cascading schedule is a subset of Recoverable schedule**.

```
    T1        T2      

    R(A)
    W(A)
    Commit;
              R(A)
              W(A)
              Commit;
```

This above schedule is Cascade less and recoverable. But then one more doubt comes to my mind is. what is this schedule (Below).

```
    T1        T2       T3

    R(A)
    W(A)
              R(A)
              W(A)
    Commit;
              Commit;
                       R(A)
                       W(A)
                       Commit;
```

T1 and T2 are cascading but T3 is not.**Is it Cascading and Recoverable**

Answer (score 1):

Here, transactions T1 and T2 are cascaded and recoverable( since T2 reads A which was written by T1, and T1 commits before T2) .
T3 and (T1 + T2) are cascadeless . Since all cascadeless schedules are recoverable, all of T1,T2,T3 are recoverable .

Have a look at this : http://coddicted.com/recoverable-and-cascadeless-schedules/

Answer (score 0):

T1 & T2 are recoverable since, the transaction starting first is the one which is being committed first. Also, any failure in T1 after W(A) by T2 leads to rolling back of both the transactions, therefore T1 &T2 are also cascading.